Gate latch installed on angled gate door
I had a fence installed recently.  The company installed the gate as outswing (is what I wanted), but left it as a lone swing gate.  No latch or spot to properly install a latch.  The gate closed is at roughly a 45° angle to a wood shed.  I want to install a latch to be opened by both sides, ie pool safety latch.  Any thoughts?  And it's a wooden fence.
![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10

Please show some photos. Some up close and clear where you think a latch of some type could be attached. Without this info your question is not answerable.

![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10

![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10

Use a "top of the gate" latch, like this:

You can add a small piece of lumber at the angle if needed, to align the latch to the strike plate.
